# Unable to use SageMaker JumpStart with S3 authorization error

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio, amazon-sagemaker-jumpstart

I'm using SageMaker Studio in an account, in VPC mode. Studio has the default SageMaker full access policy, but I'm seeing this error -

```
Something went wrong. please ensure that your account is authorized to read from S3.
```

Screenshot below -
[image]

I added full access to S3 to my role as well. Are there specific S3 permissions required for JumpStart? The domain has access to S3 through a VPC endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the permissions I've set up to close this thread -

For your Studio user's execution role, set up this IAM policy as an inline policy (replace `us-west-2` with your region) -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::jumpstart-cache-prod-us-west-2",
                "arn:aws:s3:::jumpstart-cache-prod-us-west-2/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

For my case, my Studio domain was set up in VPC only mode, and the S3 VPC endpoint had a restrictive policy as well. If you do have an S3 VPC endpoint policy, add the below policy statement to your VPCe policy -

```
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::jumpstart-cache-prod-us-west-2",
                "arn:aws:s3:::jumpstart-cache-prod-us-west-2/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The role needs access to `jumpstart-cache-prod-<Region>` bucket. Make sure your IAM role and VPC endpoint policy allow access to the JumpStart bucket.

Comment: Thank you! VPCe policy was missing permissions to the bucket.

Comment: Please supply more info on how-to